# Converting OCaml to F#: Converting OCaml quotation add and quotation expander to F#

Tags: f#, ocaml

I am converting several modules based on OCaml to F# and ran into the OCaml ''Quotation.add'' compiler directive for a quotation expander.

> A quotation expander is a function written in OCaml.  A call to the
>   Camlp4 library function ''Quotation.add''  adds the quotation
>   expander.

[Camlp4 - Tutorial, Ch. 3](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-camlp4/manual004.html)

After searching for both a quotation expander and the ''Quotation.add'' compiler directive in F# books, the F# site, Google and here, the answer I get is no.

Can someone confirm that F# does not support the concept of the OCaml ''Quotation.add'' compiler directive or the concept of OCaml quotation expanders.

EDIT

Note: I just learned that Camlp4 is a preprocessor-pretty-printer of OCaml, I thought it was a separate library for OCaml when I asked the question; now it makes sense.

Comment: You're correct - the campl4 library is not available for F#, so I'm afraid you'll need to use another approach to re-implement the functionality you need in F#. Can you share more details about the functions you're converting?

Comment: I thought that was pretty basic answer, but I added some more pointers that might be relevant (for you or other readers).

Comment: @TomasPetricek It may be a basic answer, but knowing that it doesn't exist saves me a lot of work looking for something that doesn't exist. As we know, some people don't look at comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're correct - the camlp4 library is not available for F#, so I'm afraid you'll need to use another approach to re-implement the required functionality in F#.

In general, there are a couple of related technologies that you can use from F# (but it is hard to tell if any of them is useful for you without knowing more about the specific problem):

- [F# Quotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx) allow you to manipulate F# code, but have limited compilation capabilities (are good i.e. for translating F# to SQL, JavaScript or perhaps GPU)
- [F# CodeDom](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) (from F# PowerPack) allows you to generate code and compile it using F# compiler, but you can either generate code as text or using .NET object-oriented style.
- [T4 Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) is a .NET templating mechanism, though last time I checked, it did not support F# (but I think the Mono version might work)
- [F# Type Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509(v=vs.110).aspx) (thanks to kvb) make it possible to generate types by F# plugin for a compiler. This handles cases where you're using camplp4 to generate some types to be used later (i.e. from a shorter specification), but they have only limited  use if you need to generate some code

Comment: Type providers may also be of interest, if targeting F# 3.0 is an option.